# Spring Data Rest: replace entity containing embedded collection using PUT

Tags: spring, rest, spring-data-rest

I have an entity exposed via a repository annotated with @RepositoryRestResource that contains a collection (one-to-many) of another entity (called Seat) which is not exposed via a repository.
I am trying to update the exposed entity (called Packet) using http PUT sending json representing the whole entity including the collection of Seats.
I am expecting the existing data to be replaced, however the collection of Seats contains an additional set of data after the PUT completes, i.e. Spring is adding the Seats to the existing collection, rather than replacing them.

I am using Spring Boot 1.4.0

```
@Entity
public class Packet extends BaseEntity {

  @OneToMany(....CascadeType.ALL...)
  public @Getter List<Seat> additionalSeats;

  public void setAdditionalSeats(List<Seat> additionalSeats) {
    this.additionalSeats = additionalSeats;
    if (additionalSeats != null) {
        for (Seat bs : additionalSeats) {
            bs.setPacket(this);
        }
    }
  }
}

@Entity
public class Seat extends BaseEntity {

  private @Getter @Setter String price;
  private @Getter @Setter String itemName;
  private @Getter @Setter int count;

  @ManyToOne
  private @Getter @Setter Packet packet;
}
```

Is there any way to replace items in the embedded collection?

Comment: Are you posting the Packets JSON with their primary key included?

Comment: @FrederikHeremans Sorry, have to correct: the son does contain _links property with self and Packet hrefs. But there are no IDs in the JSON.

Comment: The Url I am sending PUT to contains the ID of the packet, something like: localhost/api/packets/123.

Comment: The data in Packet itself is replaced, but the seats are added to the existing ones, rather than being replaced.

Comment: I tried writing a test case in java and that turned out to be illuminating: its not possible to update the additionalSeats, i.e. if I retrieve the list of seats and modify I get an exception that the collection is unmodifiable when I tried to save the packet entity. Instead I need to delete the packet and store a new one with a copy of the changed data. And doing precisely that via REST (with DELETE and POST) also works.